# Do I need to install extra drivers on an Aspire 4750 6801?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, hardware, aspire

I have an aspire 4750 6801. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to install the hardware drivers but I got this message: "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system". I would like to know if it is a problem or is there going to be problems in the future.

I'll really appreciate any help. Mostly if you can help me to install at least the graph.

Answer (score 2):

If the `jockey` program searched for drivers and didn't find any then most likely you do not need any proprietary drivers, the free drivers will support your computer just fine.

Doing a(very quick) internet search it seems that your computer is Intel based.  If that is correct, then you should have not reason to need additional driver installed. The only thing you might need drivers for would be a extra graphics card(Nvidia for example), the `jockey` program usually finds the graphics card without any problem, so it is highly unlikely that you need one.

The driver for most of your software is already part of the Linux kernel, that is why the additional drivers window comes up blank; all your hardware is already supported.

If you know that you have a non-integrated graphic card but the additional drivers program is not finding it you need to post another question with just the specific information that you have **X** graphic card but that is is not found by the additional drivers program `jockey`

Not sure I understand the last part of your question, I don't know what you mean by **"install the graph"** no programs come to mind with that description, could you clarify exactly what function you are trying to accomplish...